# Bad Storage property: unknown cause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

What is causing this **Bad Storage property: '_employeeId' on member 'resetQueryStatus.Employee.employeeId'.** exception?

The exception seems to be at my connection point here:

```
 [Database]
public class FireEvacuation : DataContext
{
    public Table<Employee> EmployeeDetails;
    public Table<EmpDepartment> Department;
    public Table<EmpStatus> Status;

    **public FireEvacuation(string connection) : base(connection) { }** //exception thrown here
}
```

## employeeDetails entity class

```
//create class and map it to FireEvacuation table
[Table(Name = "EmployeeDetails")]
public class Employee
{
    public string _employeeId;
    //designate employeeId property on the entity class as representing column in the database table
    //employeeId is designated to be a primary key column in the database
    //employeeName is designated as private storage ==> allows LINQ to SQL to directly store and retrieve values
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_employeeId", DbType = "int(System.Int32) NOT NULL")]
    public string employeeId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._employeeId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._employeeId = value;
        }

    }

    public string _employeeName;
    //designate employeeName property on the entity class as representing column in the database table
    //employeeName is designated as private storage ==> allows LINQ to SQL to directly store and retrieve values
    [Column(Storage = "_employeeName", DbType = "nvarchar(50) NULL")]
    public string employeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._employeeName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._employeeName = value;
        }

    }

    public string _departmentId;
    [Column(Storage = "_departmentId", DbType = "int(System.Int32) NULL")]
    public string departmentId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._departmentId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._departmentId = value;
        }
    }

    public string _statusId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_statusId", DbType = "int(System.Int32) NULL")]
    public string statusId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._statusId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._statusId = value;
        }

    }

}
```

## Department entity class

```
 [Table(Name = "Department")]
public class EmpDepartment
{
    public string _departmentId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_departmentId", DbType = "int(System.Int32) NOT NULL")]
    public string departmentId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._departmentId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._departmentId = value;
        }

    }

    public string _departmentName;
    [Column(Storage = "_departmentName", DbType = "nvarchar(50) NOT NULL")]
    public string departmentName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._departmentName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._departmentName = value;
        }

    }
}
```

## Status entity class

```
[Table(Name = "Status")]
public class EmpStatus
{
    public string _statusId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_statusId", DbType = "int(System.Int32) NOT NULL")]
    public string statusId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._statusId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._statusId = value;
        }

    }

    public string _statusDescription;
    [Column(Storage = "_statusDescription", DbType = "nvarchar(50) NOT NULL")]
    public string statusName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._statusDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            this._statusDescription = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's my query code to get values from the above entities:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Use a connection string.
        FireEvacuation db = new FireEvacuation
            (@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\runSqlLinq\FireEvacuation.mdf");

        do
        {

            // Attach the log to show generated SQL.
            db.Log = Console.Out;

            string name = "John";

            //Query for account status
                var query = from emp in db.EmployeeDetails
                            join stat in db.Status on emp._statusId equals stat._statusId
                            join dep in db.Department on emp._departmentId equals dep._departmentId
                            where emp._employeeName == name
                            select new { emp, stat, dep };

                foreach (var q in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Department Name = {0} Employee Name = {1} Status Name = {2}", q.dep._departmentName, q.emp._employeeName, q.stat._statusDescription);
                }

        }
        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
        //Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }//end of main
```

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found my error:

Storage field/ property cannot be public.

The moment it was private, the issue was gone. Hopes this helps others with the same issue next time. :)